# How to find Maclaurin series of $cos^2(x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

How to find Maclaurin series of $\cos^2(x)$ from $\cos(x)$.

Maclaurin Series of $\cos(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+.....$

Then how to find for $\cos^2(x)$ from $\cos(x)$.

For the $cos^2(x)$, I thought of just squaring the right hand side.

Please explain me the method.

Comment: Use $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$ and then use the MacLaurin Series for cos.

Comment: What have you tried? If you know the maclurin series for cos(x) already, what do you have to do to turn cos(x) into cos^2(x)? @josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It becomes far easier if you invoke this trig identity.
$$\cos^2(x) = {1 + \cos(2x)\over 2}.$$

Comment: Isn't is, rather, $cos^2(x)$ which is asked ?

Comment: I asked for cos^2(x)